# How to fix tooltip "text on hover" over paths of images with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I am new to javascript and I am having a problem when linking the .js file to the .html one. It is working fine in codepen, but when i implement it in visual code studio, the text on hover doesn't show. I linked the .js file with the general syntax "https://codepen.io/przemoo83/pen/vJPvmy
Ps: I want to use javascript for the tooltip "text on hover" so that i could later on be able to update that data through a channel. Do you think that it is a good idea, or could i just use css and still be able to update it later on ? or will i need to use php, since the data is coming from a server?
Thank you guys

Comment: Without seeing a page or some example code we can't really know what the problem is

Comment: @RobKwasowski this is the code https://codepen.io/przemoo83/pen/vJPvmy 
but in visual code studio the .js part doesn't seem to work

Comment: I'm having a look now. I can see that on CodePen you get a tooltip on the buttons 1,2 & 3. But you're saying that in Visual Studio it doesn't work? Can you explain what you mean by this? You are running the page actually in Visual Studio? Or in a web browser like Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that perhaps you have simply failed to include all the right imports in your local HTML file, or perhaps put them in the wrong order or in the wrong place in the file.

I have set it up as the following and if you use this it should be fine. Just make sure you have all the external resources mentioned in your HTML, so that means `bootstrap.min.css` for CSS, and `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` in that order. Bootstrap needs jQuery to be loaded first for it to run. And then your own linked or embedded JS should be third, as this is referencing both.

If you look in your browser's Developer window (press F12 for Chrome) it will show you any error messages that will help you to fix problems.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.path').tooltip({container:'.img-container'});
});
```

```css
.img-container {
  width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
path {
  fill: transparent;
  transition: 1s;
  stroke: transparent;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#screen:hover {
  fill: red;
}
#one:hover {
  stroke: green;
}
#two:hover {
  fill: blue;
  stroke: yellow
}
#three:hover {
  fill: grey;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>z</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href="/mysite/static/.other/z.css">
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script src='/mysite/static/.other/z.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="img-container">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 960 714" height="100%" width="100%" version="1.1" id="svg4160">
      <image width="960" height="714" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="http://i68.tinypic.com/apa4x0.png" id="" />
      <path class="path" id="screen" data-placement="top" title="Screen!" d="m 303.80326,47.378347 263.07451,144.628633 0.41559,3.3248 -187.85098,154.18743 -6.6496,1.6624 -265.5681,-174.96741 z" />
      <path id="one" class="path" data-placement="top" title="One!" d="m 511.81083,476.48487 32.00116,22.44237 10.80559,7.68859 4.57159,1.039 2.078,-1.4546 67.11933,-60.05413 1.039,-2.4936 -16.00059,-12.26018 -27.01397,-16.41619 -2.07799,-1.24679 -1.2468,0.4156 -22.85798,19.74097 -47.79394,39.48196 z" />
      <path class="path" id="two" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Two!" d="m 589.52794,411.23574 29.09197,17.66298 13.50698,11.01339 3.3248,0 77.71711,-78.34052 -1.039,-2.70139 -14.54598,-9.76659 -25.14377,-14.54599 -4.3638,-1.45459 -2.70139,2.07799 -76.67812,73.56112 1.4546,2.2858 z" />
      <path class="path" id="three" data-placement="top" title="Three!" d="m 670.77765,331.23283 29.50757,15.37718 13.09138,9.97439 4.5716,0.4156 47.58614,-53.61234 0.8312,-3.117 -13.71478,-8.10419 -30.54657,-16.41618 -1.4546,0.8312 -48.41734,51.74214 z" />
    </svg>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much you just made my whole week, it does finally work. I was really desperate since I tried installing external libraries, but it was just the .js src code that I was missing. Thanks again for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @SlowmoCitizen Thanks, I'm glad I could help. Once you get to 15 reputation you'll be able to upvote answers. If you could come back and give me an upvote I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes I tried upvoting it but as you mentioned I don't have yet the 15 reputation's points, of course i ll bookmark it so that i can go back to it later on and gladly give you an upvote :D

Comment: @SlowmoCitizen Thanks dude